# Alternate for document-start in Opera browser

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events, opera-extension

I have seen "@run-at  document-start" and "contentScriptWhen: 'start' " in Firefox extension(or userscript).

All these statements are used to run some scripts, while the web page starts loading in Firefox.

Now I want to run my script at document start in Opera extension (or userscript).

How to catch this start event in Opera browser?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is actually the default behaviour of opera user javascript.

- Gotcha #1: *your script **must** have .js extension, and not .user.js*
- Gotcha #2: when you use .js userscript you have to manually listen for loading events.

But, imho the price for the power you get - is not that high ;)